# Python, reading and slicing text in realtime and uploading to online

Tags: python

I have a file where another script writes data every second or longer (max 60s). I have a very basic script that opens the file, reads the data and slices the ones I want to use. (SCRIPT AT THE END, with sample data).

1St problem:

My script reads ALL the lines from the file, how to edit the script so it reads only the last/newest line?

2Nd:

How can I print the data to console only when there is data to show? I don't quite understand how to use len() when reading file.

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time

f = open("output.json", "r")
ID = slice(17,24)
Voltage = slice(25,29)

while True:
    k = f.readline()
    print ("ID:", k[ID])
    print ("Voltage:",k[Voltage])
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

The file where other script is writing (output.json)

```
00000000;183;014;1004d9d;2705;2447;6498;1083;2447;S
00000000;183;015;1004d9d;2730;2518;6348;1058;2518;S
```

After the script given above has done it's weak magic, this is the output:

```
ID: 1004d9d #Data received and shows it properly.
Voltage: 2810
ID: 1004d9d

Voltage: #After there is no data received, this will happen.
ID: 
Voltage: 
ID: 
Voltage:
```

Comment: Your json file is not json.

Comment: well, its fine. Whatever it prints i am happy. Text/csv everything works if it works.

Comment: Hi @Thomashamka have you had a chance to try my revised answer? I believe it should do what you're expecting.

Comment: @David zemens, Hi, we had a long weekend from school and cannot access internet outside of it. I will try it now and I believe it will work very nicely, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ingest the file contents all at once and take the last line using the index `-1` slice, then unpack the data and print it.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
import time

ID = slice(17,24)
Voltage = slice(25,29)

with open("output.json", "r") as f:  # use with block to open the file
    k = f.readlines()                # read the entire file

line = k[-1]                     # take the last line only
i, v = line[ID].strip(), line[Voltage].strip()   # unpack the line contents

if i or v:                       # ensure there is something to print
    print("ID: {}\tVoltage: {}".format(i, v))
```

To apply this in continual loop (sorry, I didn't quite understand this until you explained in comments), you will need to repeatedly open the file, and compare the last line of data so that you don't repeatdly write the same information:

```
  #!/usr/bin/python3
  import time
  ID, Voltage = slice(17,24), slice(25,29)
  i, v, line = '', '', ''
  while True:
      with open(r"c:\debug\file.txt", "r") as f:  # use with block to open the file
          k = f.readlines()                # read the entire file
      if line != k[-1]:                    # make sure the line is "new"
          line = k[-1] 
          i, v = line[ID].strip(), line[Voltage].strip()   # unpack the line contents
          if i or v:                       # ensure there is something to print
              print("ID: {}\tVoltage: {}".format(i, v))
      time.sleep(.5)
```

Comment: I thought I got the idea how to use this, but I didn't. How to use this code as continuous loop, so that it won't post the same, do I need to use timestamps in the text file("json") so I can look for the newest only? Thanks alot.

Comment: Hi @Thomashamka ; I did not understand that part, initially. I have made a revision in my answer to allow "continuous" monitoring of the file, and to only print to console when the file changes in the last line.

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help (I'm new to python too, so I learn a lot by trying to help others here). If this had solved the problem, do consider marking the answer as "accepted" :)